# Processing all files in a folder automatically

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a lot of files in a folder that needs to be process through a function that I have written in Mathematica. I need help writing a code that would process all the files automatically.

```
TestData = Import["file.xls"];

function[input_] := 
 Module[{CellsKey, Datalist, Lastcap, Pdata, filename},
  Datalist = {};
  CellsKey = TestData[[1]][[1]][[1]];
  a = Last[TestData[[1]]];
  Lastcap = a[[4]];
  (*Print[Lastcap]*)
  Pdata = Append[CellsKey, Lastcap]
    (*Print[CellsKey]*)
    Print[Pdata]
]
```

This is what I have so far. With this code, I could only import one file at a time.

Comment: Make TestData or the file name part of the function parameters. Then `Map` this function of a list of file names, which you can  obtain using `FileNames`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Similar question was closed: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31984/5478

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the notebook path to the folder in which the files you wish to process are located. For example, in the same folder as the current notebook.

```
myNBpath = SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

Get a list of all the filenames in your designated folder matching some filename string.

```
nblist = FileNames["filesOfInterest*.nb"];
```

Now start a `Do` loop to process all the files whose filenames have been stored in the `nblist` variable. There is almost certainly a more elegant and efficient Mathematica way to do this without a `Do` list.

```
Do[
  (* Place code here to process those files as you wish. *)

  Pause[1]; (* Sometimes a pause of a second or so helps. *)
  ,
  {ichg, 1, Length[nblist]} (* Keep Do-ing this processing until all the designated files have been processed *)
];

Beep[]; (* Optional: make a warning sound when all the files have been processed. *)

Print["- Finished making clean files -"] (* Optional: print a message in the Mathematica notebook when all the files have been processed. *)
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. I imported my all my files with your code. When I run my function, the function only output data from of the first file only.

Comment: I wrote this according to what you suggested. 
Input: 
`myNBpath = SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];`
`TestData = FileNames["Cell_*"];`
`Print[TestData]`
Output: `{Cell_0079_103L.xls, Cell_0079_103M.xls}`
`FileNames` only sees those two files as a list of two items, instead of two giant lists of data.

Comment: You have placed the FileNames in your TestData variable. If you want the data stored in those files placed in your TestData variable, you have to `Import` them, for example, as follows: `TestData[[ichg]] = Import[nblist[[ichg]]];` – Place this code in the `Do` loop where it says `(* Place code here *)`

Comment: Note that this code, using a `Do` loop, is a procedural programming approach, which is quite clunky compared to the elegant and efficient functional programming approach as offered by Sjoerd de Vries.

Answer (score 3):

As Sjoerd de Vrjes said, the way to go may be:

```
function[inputfile_String] :=
Module[{CellsKey, Datalist, Lastcap, Pdata, filename},
  If[FileExistsQ[inputfile],
    TestData = Import[inputfile];
    (* your code *)
  ,
    (* if the file does not exist *)
    Print["The file ", inputfile, "does not exist"];
  ]
];

function /@ FileNames["*.xls"]
```

The symbol /@ indicates that the function is applied to all the elements in the list of the file names

Comment: Don't I have to set "inputfile" to equal something? I have thousands of files to process.... I don't think I can individually list them out.