# Is there a more practical way to remove backgrounds from a list of files in a folder on my computer?

Tags: image-processing, image, files-and-directories

Is there a more practical way to remove backgrounds from a list of files in a folder on my computer?

**Example:**

Imagine a folder with three image files... Unfortunately I waste time manually renaming the files in the folders so that my code can be done ...

[image]

The code below eliminates the background and adds a suffix to differentiate the files:

```
n=3;(*Number of files*)
a=Import[StringReplace[StringJoin[{{"C:\\Users\\LeandroCarvalho\\Pictures\\"},ToString[(#."png")]}],Whitespace->""]]&/@Range[n]
list=ImageCrop[RemoveBackground[a[[#]],White]]&/@Range[n]
Export[StringReplace[StringJoin[{{"C:\\Users\\LeandroCarvalho\\Pictures\\"},ToString[(#"A.png")]}],Whitespace->""],list[[#]],"PNG"]&/@Range[n]
```

The result is satisfactory...

[image]

...but I was thinking of making this code cleaner and adding something that eliminates my manual file renaming action

***Files used in the test:***

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This: `ImageCrop[RemoveBackground[a[[#]],White]]&/@Range[n]`. There's no need to re-index `a`. Just do `ImageCrop[RemoveBackground[#,White]]&/@a`. The same goes for the next line too.

Comment: Would you have a practical way to use the files in the folder without renaming them numerically?

Comment: Do you want to operate on the files in-place? That's possible but you risk corrupting or losing files permanently if the Mathematica crashes for some reason mid-way through processing them.

Comment: Yes, files in place... But something without changing them but creating copies ...

Comment: If you create a copy it has to have a different name or go in another directory. What you've done already is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will remove background and crop all the PNG images (with .png extension) in a folder, without manually renaming the files. The method is based on this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39928/41569) to a question about processing all files in a folder automatically.

```
function[inputFile_String] := Module[{image, cropped, fileName},
   image = Import[inputFile];
   cropped = ImageCrop[RemoveBackground[image, White]];
   fileName = StringReplace[inputFile, ".png"->"A.png"];
   Export[fileName, cropped , "PNG"];
];
```

Get the list of files in a folder, crop, and save each file with "A" added to the original file name.

```
SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\LeandroCarvalho\\Pictures"];
function /@ FileNames["*.png"];
ResetDirectory[];
```